# PHP расширение v8js - класс не определен

Tags: php, extension

Доброго времени суток!

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь в решении, для меня важной, проблемы!

Буду краток.

Конфигурация:

- x64
- apache 2.4
- php 7.1 TS

Необходимо использовать js код в php. 
Под реализацию решено использовать расширение v8js [Ссылка на PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/v8js)
Был скачан скомпилированный php со всеми расширениями и подключен к apache.

- При запуске веб-сервера в логах все отлично.
- echo phpinfo(); выдает, что расширение подключено.
  [image: phpinfo()]

Проблема:

1. PHP уведомляет, что класс не определен.

[image: Класс не определен]

2. Список загруженных расширений

[image: PHP функция для определения загруженных расширений]

Под номером 38 красуется наш v8js.

[image: Список загруженных расширений]

3. Выдача списка функций расширения

[image: Функция для выдачи списка функций расширения]

Возвращает пустой массив. Но при передаче в аргумент имён других расширений, функция выдает полный список всех команд.

[image: Команда для вывод]

[image: Функция для выдачи списка функций расширения]

Вопросы:

1. Почему расширение не загрузилось фактически? Как-будто существует только обертка. (Расширение весит ~200 кб)
2. Какими способами можно еще проверить работоспособность расширения? (логи, ошибки)
3. Почему так сложно?)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не получилось подключить v8js расширение. Решил другим образом, а именно через exec(node.exe arg). Установил node. Через функцию php exec выполнил node js скрипт, в которую передал свои аргументы.
Всем спасибо!